# Js if multiple values check if ==

Tags: javascript

I can create like that code in js? if example == 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 { code here } else if { code here }  I mean check example have one of this value

I dont wanna create many lines code example if == 0 , if == 2 ets
Thanks for help

Comment: Are you wanting to compare against those exact values? Or are you wanting to see if `example` is even?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is compare your 'example' with each of the values.

let's assume your array is 2,4,6,8,0

then what you can do is

```
let example = 3;
let array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

if (array.includes(example)) {
// true statement
} else {
// false statement
}
```

Comment: Yes , thanks dear , I need simple code like that. I will try it now

Comment: its not ten , ites 0 but its doesnt matter. Thanks you so much. Have a great day all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and check the values via a loop and based on that return either false or true, look at the snippet below. The values should be in an array!

```js
function checkValue(value){
    for (let i of [0,2,4,6,8]){
      if (i === value) {
       return false;
      }
    }
    
    return true;
}

console.log('3: ', checkValue(3));
console.log('8: ', checkValue(8));
```

Alternatively if you want to see if the value is an odd number or not, you can use the remainder operator:

```js
let i = 3;
console.log(i%2 === 1)
```

Comment: no problem, however you need to do more research before you ask a question here, most users wont answer your question, if you didnt show your research effort